# Data Validation (List) Excel: Colors

Tags: excel, list, format

I´ve got a excel with several cells with different background colours.

I would like to create a cell of type "List". I create using "DataValidation".

The cell has the values but the problem is that I also want that when i select an option, this option appears in its colors. In the past, I did it, but now the only solution it is "Conditional Format" but the problem it is that i have to create about 20 rules(i´ve got 20 cells). I didn´t do that in the past.

Is there another solution?

Best regards,
Antonio

Comment: Solution would be `Conditional Formatting` or `VBA`.

Comment: How can be done with VBA?

Comment: I´ve been looking another excel and is done with "Conditional Formatting" but I don´t remember how I did it.

Comment: Have you tried [**Google**](https://www.google.com/search?q=excel+conditional+formatting+based+on+text&oq=excel+conditional+formatting+based&aqs=chrome.2.0j69i57j0l4.12318j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) search...?